# How can I get jsFiddle to work in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know why, but jsFiddle isn't working in Chrome. It worked fine until a few days ago, but now, when I open the console I receive this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of null
```

Is there or bug and what I need to do to make it work?

Comment: Read the comments here http://blog.jsfiddle.net/post/39954467099/jsfiddle-updated#disqus_thread

Comment: @user1788747: Valid question only though because jsFiddle is used for a huge percentage of SO question regarding jQuery which makes this a completely relevant programming question in my humble opinion. I was myself battling with this and the UI (the CSS they used) kept changing as well every now and then indicating the guys from jsFiddle must be in the middle of working on it. So I just left it and came back a few days later only to see the issue still existed. After clearing the cache it all worked again.

Comment: saw @dystroy's answer? doesn't it work for you? are you planning to mark the answer?

Answer (score 14):

Simply empty your cache and it will work again.

They built a new version, bringing many improvements, but they forgot to handle cache.

Comment: @user1788747: This answer should really be marked as accepted as it is real important information and will probably even apply if users experience similar issues in future jsfiddle changes/releases. +1 off course to `dystroy`.